# Android checkbox default behaviour is different on phones and tablets

Tags: android, checkbox

I am using a standard android checkbox in my application like this.

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

The checkbox's default behavior of checked is displayed in phones but it remains unchecked in tablets. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: You should default it in the CheckBox to what you would like if you are concerned with unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
 android:checked="true"
```

Comment: Thanks that did help. Although, i was programmatically doing something wrong and had to update the code

Comment: @kapalani if you are satisfied with my answer kindly accept it